# removing dote from menu items in html

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I am trying to add menu bar in my html page. The icons added come with underline and dote behind. I removed underline using text-decoration=none; but it does not remove dote. what should I do?

Comment: please try to add your create a code snippet with your code

Comment: list-style-type: none;

Answer (score 1):

If you could have added code then it would have been easier to answer.

Example:
If you have used "ul" element for your menu to specify various menu items, then on your "ul" element, you can apply:

```
ul{
"list-style-type: none;"
}
```

To remove the dots/ bullet points.